# $L^2$ martingales relation to martingales?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Are all continuous time $L^2$-martingales i.e martingales such that $\mathbb{E}X_{t}^2<\infty$ for all $t$ also martingales in the sense that  $\mathbb{E}\mid X_{t} \mid<\infty$ for all $t$, which is the common definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are. Martingales have finite first moment and $L^{2}$ martingales are martingales with the extra condition that second moments are also finite.

Comment: This follows also from the Lp inclusion and the fact that $\mathbb{E}\mid X_{t} \mid<\infty$ is equivallent to $\mathbb{E} X_{t} <\infty$, right?

Comment: @Probablynot Yes, $L^{2} \subset L^{1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  $L_2 \subset L_1$ as
$$|X|<1+|X|^2.$$

Comment: Isnt it the other way around?

Comment: I don't think so. Look at the plot if in doubt.

Comment: $L_1 \subset L_2$ is wrong.

Comment: Oh yes, right. I'll edit.